# uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression option:contains

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `col model` from my jqgrid

```
 colModel: [
           { name: 'rowId', index: 'rowId', hidden: true, width: 20 },
           { name: 'CompleteName', index: 'CompleteName', hidden: false, editable: true, sortable: false, width: 160, align: 'center' }
           ],
```

I have this code for the `onSelectRow`

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {
        var objRowData = jQuery("#FAList").getRowData(id);
        var CompleteName = objRowData.CompleteName;
        $("#divFieldAssignment #EmpId option:contains (" + CompleteName + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
        alert(CompleteName);
    },
```

But it gives me an error `uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression` but on my other code it is working fine. What's wrong with it?.

Comment: Can you show us the context in which this code is being used? Also, a more descriptive error would help too! (for example, _what_ expression is unrecognized? Where is the error occurring in your code?)

Comment: `option:contains (` remove the space?

Comment: @JaromandaX oh crap. I thought it doesn't matter the `white space` Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you don't mind I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the white space between contains and (

```
$("#divFieldAssignment #EmpId option:contains (" + CompleteName + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
                                             ^
```

removing the space will fix the error.

White space in a CSS selector is a delimiter? between one part of a selector and the next

`contains` isn't valid

`contains(whatever)` is valid